# How can I access the value of a select element with jQuery on mobile?

Tags: jquery, select, mobile

My code is only breaking on mobile devices (only phones tested so far [iOS and Android]). I've been troubleshooting this for a while already and have narrowed the problem down to this simplification. With this HTML:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/processor.php" method="get" onsubmit="return foo.validate();">
    <select name="selectElement">
        <option value="">Nothing</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>  
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
</form>
```

I use this jQuery (linked from an outside file):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#button').click(function(e){
        var val = jQuery('select[name=selectElement] option:selected').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        alert (val);
    });
});
```

and when I run it in a desktop, it alerts the value I selected, either nothing, 1, 2, or 3. But when I run it on a phone, all it ever alerts is nothing/empty string/nada/bubkiss regardless which option is selected. Does anyone know how I can access the value of the selected option on mobiles? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the selectElemet in double quotes :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#button').click(function(e){
        var val = jQuery('select[name="selectElement"] option:selected').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        alert (val);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've continued to work on this, I've discovered that the code I've posted here does work. There's was something else in my coding environment (by which I mean the remainder of the site where this code lives) that's causing the problem.

**Thanks for your efforts everybody!**